# how to grow grass where an underground pool once was

Tags: lawn-repair

This is my third year of trying to grow grass where an underground pool once was. It keeps dying off over the winter.  Is there anything I can do? Or should I opt to put something else in this 12'X 12' spot.

Comment: Please tell us more. Did you remove the pool first or just fill it in? What did you use to fill in the hole? How deep was the pool? What is your climate like (include a geographical area if you feel comfortable doing that)? What kind of grass are you planting and is it the same kind as the rest of your lawn?